# Format date without dash?

Tags: python, date

In Python, we can convert a date to a string by:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date(2002, 12,4).isoformat()
'2002-12-04'
```

How can we format the output to be '20021204', i.e. without dashes?

There are  two functions, but I don't know how to specify the format:

> `date.strftime(format)`
>   Return a string representing the date,
>   controlled by an explicit format string. Format codes referring to
>   hours, minutes or seconds will see 0 values. For a complete list of
>   formatting directives, see section `strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior.

and

> `date.__format__(format)`
>   Same as `date.strftime()`. This makes it
>   possible to specify format string for a date object when using
>   `str.format()`. See section `strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are using the wrong tool for your job, use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

```
>>> datetime.date(2002, 12,4).strftime("%Y%m%d")
'20021204'
```

For details on using [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) and [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), refer [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

For your particular case, I will quote the relevant excerpt

- %Y    Year with century as a decimal number.            1970, 1988, 2001, 2013
- %m    Month as a zero-padded decimal number.            01, 02, ..., 12
- %d    Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number. 01, 02, ..., 31

alternatively, you could have always removed or replaced the hyphen from the `isoformat`

```
>>> str(datetime.date(2002, 12,4)).translate(None,'-')
'20021204'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `'%m%d%Y` as your format :

```
>>> d=datetime.date(2002, 12,4)
>>> d.strftime('%m%d%Y')
'12042002'
```

Or in your first code, you can use `str.replace` :

```
>>> datetime.date(2002, 12,4).isoformat().replace('-','')
'20021204'
```