# Find file with newest name (YYYYMMDD.rar format)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a newbie working on a python 3.6 script and I can't figure out how to locate the newest file in a directory, according to their naming convention (YYYYMMDD.rar). Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Hi. It's fine that you ask but we can't write entire code for you. Check function `strptim()` from datetime module and `os` module, try to solve the problem on your own and if you still have problems you can return here and we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code example as a hint for how you can solve this problem.

I'll assume that dates specified in the `YYYYMMDD.rar` format are always valid dates.

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime

def is_correct_file_format(text):
    """
    Checks if a specified text input is of the correct
    datetime format %Y%m%d.
    """
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(text, '%Y%m%d.rar')
    except ValueError:
        print(text, "is in wrong file format")
        return False

def get_list_of_datetime_files():
    """
    Main function. Goes through the files in a directory (the same
    folder that contains this .py script) and returns a list of
    file names that correspond to the format %Y%m%d.rar given in
    the function is_correct_file_format(text).
    """
    list_of_files_in_dir = os.listdir()
    return list(filter(is_correct_file_format, list_of_files_in_dir))

# WORKS for:
# 20180117.rar, 20180118.rar, 20150217.rar, etc.
#
# BUT NOT:
# somefile.rar, somefile.py, 201801.rar, 2018010.rar, 201801171.rar
print(list(get_list_of_datetime_files()))
```

---

**A short explanation:**

1. A breakdown of what the pattern `%Y%m%d` means from the `strptime` function:

   - %Y Year with century as a decimal number. 1970, 1988, 2001, 2013
   - %m Month as a zero-padded decimal number. 01, 02, ..., 12
   - %d Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number. 01, 02, ..., 31

Apart from the use of the `strptime` function from the `datetime` module, you might also want to explore the limitations it has to your date format `YYYYMMDD` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295402/format-date-without-dash). In this example, I just used `strptime` for simplicity.

2. Also, `os.listdir(path_to_some_directory)` returns a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by the path `path_to_some_directory`.

I hope that this is a helpful hint for you to get started.

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check-mark! This indicates to the wider community that you've found a possible solution and for further references :)