# use python datetime.strptime

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I want to convert a string to a date format using Python datetime.strptime.

However, I set the format to '%m/%d/%y' but the result is '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S'.
What's the reason?

**convert.py**

```
date_str = ['11/10/2021', '12/15/2021', '2/26/2022', '3/10/2021', '3/10/2021', '3/11/2021']
replace_format = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

**result**

```
print(replace_format)
2022-03-14 00:00:00
2022-04-13 00:00:00
2022-05-11 00:00:00
2022-06-16 00:00:00
2022-06-18 00:00:00
2022-06-18 00:00:00
```

Comment: The default format of `datetime`, when you call print on it is used, which is `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`. You can use `replace_format.strftime('%m/%d/%y')` to achieve the desired format.

Comment: `strptime` parses a string to a datetime object. The datetime object's default *representation* (as a string) happens to be `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. But that's just a matter how it is displayed to you when you print it.

Comment: @DB not using pandas

Comment: @hoboman Thanks! Actually, the result I want is '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S'. Is there any problem if I keep setting this format to '%m/%d/%Y'?

Comment: In any case, you are using `datetime.strptime` wrongly. According documentation you must provide one string, but you pass a list. Just do not do it.

Comment: @JIN This is just a representation of the underlying object. `strftime` does not change anything in the object, it is just a string representation of it.

Answer (score 3):

Call `date()`:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_str = ['11/10/2021', '12/15/2021', '2/26/2022', '3/10/2021', '3/10/2021', '3/11/2021']
for d in date_str:
    replace_format = datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
    print(replace_format)
```

**Result:**

```
2021-11-10
2021-12-15
2022-02-26
2021-03-10
2021-03-10
2021-03-11
```

Note: Your code did not compile for me in Python 3.7 so I put each item from the date list in a loop.

Comment: I set the format to '/', but why the output is '-' ?

Comment: you can use string replace or just remove the slashes
https://stackoverflow.com/q/29295402/4225229